# TikZ framebox (simple box + text inside)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am beginning with TikZ. How to do the simplest square of defined position, width&height, eventually color with text inside please ?

I used before the command `framebox`, but I don't have the same result with TikZ.

Thanks a lot,

Thomas

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Does this help:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\MyNode}[3][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[#1] (A) at #2 {#3};
    \node [anchor=west, align=left, text width=8cm] at (A.east) {\tiny#1};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\MyNode{(0,0)}{x}

\MyNode[draw=red]{(0,0)}{1}

\MyNode[draw=red, inner sep=0, outer sep=0]{(0,0)}{2}

\MyNode[draw=red, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, minimum width=1cm]{(0,0)}{3}

\MyNode[draw=red, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, minimum height=1cm]{(0,0)}{4}

\MyNode[draw=red, inner sep=0, outer sep=0, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, fill=yellow]{(0,0)}{5}

\end{document}
```